# How to restrict MS Access DB to open

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am connecting to **MS Access DB** using **vb.net** as given below...

**oDBEngine = oAccess.DBEngine
oDB = oDBEngine.OpenDatabase(Name:=strFullFileName, Options:=False, ReadOnly:=False, Connect:="")**

And then opening the DB using the following syntex...

**oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(filepath:=strFullFileName, Exclusive:=False)**

Now my problem is:

One of the DB contains a form which opens Automatically while we are opening the DB. So when I am trying to run the application for this particular DB the DB opens up. But as per my requirement I do not need to open the DB explicitly.

Is there any way to restrict the DB to open in such cases?

NOTE: This works fine for all other scenarios i.e. DB is not opening, but I can able to count Activex controls form each form as per my application requirement.

Comment: You're connecting to a Jet database, not an Access database, as only Access itself can utilize Access objects. You're using only the data tables, which means Jet only.

Comment: Ooops. Didn't read carefully. Why are you opening the database? Do you need to run the forms, or are you just trying to access the data? If the latter, then don't open the database, but use OLEDB or some other database interface to access the data.

Answer (score 1):

You could try 'programmatically pressing the shift-key' through APIs:

http://www.mvps.org/access/api/api0068.htm

Answer (score 0):

In your previous post on this topic : [How to prevent to open a MS Access Database while reading data from forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427436/how-to-prevent-to-open-a-ms-access-database-while-reading-data-from-forms#427460), I suggested importing the forms into a blank database, you did not mention why this option did not suit, and I am curious as to why.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggetions. But it is not possible to copy from one location to another and create a new DB because, client may not give pormission to do so also in case of huse DB it may not be fisible to do so. 

Any other way to do so...